# Pages from admin dasboard missing after site migration

Tags: php, htaccess

i migrated a site which was hosted on wp-engine to my local machine, after the migration in the admin dashboard i saw most of the pages are missing. on the wp-engine server, there are **59 pages**, but there are just **29 pages** after the migration to localhost.
i have been stuck with this for a while and unable to figure out whats exactly wrong. Is that a file permissions issue or htaccess issues, i am not sure.
Please help me on this to find out what might be wrong or i am missing.

i also tried checking by uninstalling all the plugins to see if that makes any effect, but no luck.

Below is my htaccess code.

Thanks

```
php_value memory_limit 1024M
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /<sitename>/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /<sitename>/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't believe this has anything to do with `.htaccess`.

Comment: Why do you think it's related to .htaccess? Have you looked in the database to see if the posts are there?